# binary files in python: buffered reading

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

i need to read big binary files byte per byte and am trying to speed that up as much as possible.

i am using this (far from perfect) timer context:

```
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def timethis(label):
    start = time.time()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        end = time.time()
    print('%s: %0.3f' % (label, end-start))
```

then i have a test function that iterates over the given `read_funcion` byte per byte.

```
def test(read_function):
    with timethis(read_function.__name__):
        # buffering seems to make no difference
        # with DATA_PATH.open('br', buffering=8192) as file:
        with DATA_PATH.open('br') as file:
            for byte in read_function(file):
                pass
```

my `DATA_PATH` ist the [python 3.7.2 source code](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tgz)...

```
from pathlib import Path
DATA_PATH = Path('~/Downloads/Python-3.7.2.tgz').expanduser()
```

now i compared two read functions (one returns an iterator over `bytes`; the second one yields longer `bytes`; iterating over those will result in `int`s)

```
def read1(file):
    return iter(partial(file.read, 1), b"")

def read2(file):
    for buffer in iter(partial(file.read, 8192), b""):
        yield from buffer
```

when i test that with

```
test(read1)
test(read2)
```

i see significant differences: the second version is way faster.

why does the buffering paramater in the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method not yield the same speed as my hand-made buffereing? is there a better way to do this? is there something in python that does that all for me already (i was hoping `io.BufferedReader` would - but it turns out my variable `file` is already a `BufferedReader`).

Comment: [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mmap.html) has generally been helpful but probably not the answer to your question.

Comment: The buffer size is one factor. The operating system is faster fetching block-sized chunks from disk. Also, there are 8192 the amount of disk operations in read1

Comment: @RickM. oh, thanks! will look into that.

Comment: @ferrix yes, disk access takes a lot of time. therefore buffering. i was hoping the `buffering` option of `open` would take care of that.

Comment: On the first read1 you are calling the syscall for reading the file every byte, something that is inefficient, on the other version you read in blocks of 8192 bytes, reducing the number of reads considerably

Comment: @camp0 oh. `read` is the syscall. that would explain why the buffering has no effect... thanks.

Comment: If you bump read1 to 8192, I would assume your buffering will actually slow things down. Tell me how it went :D